# How to convert RDD[Row] to RDD[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame called source, a table from mysql

```
val source = sqlContext.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "source", connectionProperties)
```

I have converted it to rdd by

```
val sourceRdd = source.rdd
```

but its RDD[Row] I need RDD[String]
to  do transformations like

```
source.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0).toInt, rec)), .subtractByKey(), etc..
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you include the output of `source.printSchema`? I'd like to show you how to avoid going at RDD level (which you should not do at all cost).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Row. mkString(sep: String): String` method in a `map` call like this :

```
val sourceRdd = source.rdd.map(_.mkString(","))
```

You can change the `","` parameter by whatever you want.

Hope this help you, Best Regards.

Comment: If there will be some comma "," inside String, then your method will probably fail

Comment: @T.Gawęda  If you're talking about the string we wanna make, so we have to avoid the `","` and changed it by another separator

Answer (score 3):

What is your schema?

If it's just a String, you can use:

```
import spark.implicits._
val sourceDS = source.as[String]
val sourceRdd = sourceDS.rdd // will give RDD[String]
```

Note: use sqlContext instead of spark in Spark 1.6 - spark is a SparkSession, which is a new class in Spark 2.0 and is a new entry point to SQL functionality. It should be used instead of SQLContext in Spark 2.x

You can also create own case classes.

Also you can map rows - here source is of type DataFrame, we use partial function in map function:

```
val sourceRdd = source.rdd.map { case x : Row => x(0).asInstanceOf[String] }.map(s => s.split(","))
```

Comment: I tried the first method it throwing error --Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing sqlContext.implicits._ Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
not enough arguments for method as: (implicit evidence$1: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[String])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String]. Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.

Comment: for the second method --value split is not a member of Any

Comment: import spark.implicits._ not found: object spark

Comment: Sorry, change to sqlContext. I've used Spark 2.0's SparkSession